# Установка интерпретатора Python 3.5.2 на Windows

Tags: python, windows, интерпретатор

При попытке установки интерпретатора Python 3.5.2 выбрасывает ошибку в инсталлере выдает ошибку: 0х80240017.
В логах отыскал следующие строчки с ошибкой:Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.

```
[10A0:05E0][2016-07-05T23:24:16]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to configure per-machine MSU package.
[10A0:05E0][2016-07-05T23:24:16]i319: Applied execute package: crt_14.0_v6.3_x64, result: 0x80240017, restart: None
[10A0:05E0][2016-07-05T23:24:16]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
```

Comment: related: [Python install failed windows 8.1- Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32464714/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты можешь попробовать установить Universal C Runtime, и потом установить Python 3.5 
Вот ссылка: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2999226